# How to edit config files in docker container?

Tags: docker, configuration

I'm running DVWA on a container and I want to change the configuration files of php to `allow_url_include` option that is disabled by default. I tried to run `sudo docker run -t -i my_image /bin/bash` and edit files manually. Later on I realized that despite of my editings docker daemon always overwrites them. So I tried to use RUN command in Dockerfile when building the image. Without any sucess. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Can you share your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @RandallFlagg Sure! Please notice that is only a try...I'm not really confident on my Dockerfile. Anymway, [here](https://pastebin.com/Yw1tT1Y6) it is.

Comment: @RandallFlagg Dockerfile creates the image and then attempts to write .htaccess file